# Как получить байтовую строку из строковой переменной?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def md5(str):
    h = hashlib.md5(b"?")
    return h.hexdigest()

hashed = md5('any_str')
```

Comment: А при чём здесь md5? Это если воспринимать вопрос как есть. А если выходить за рамки: замена `hexdigest` на "просто" `digest` не решает вашей задачи?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3

Comment: Приведите более конкретный пример: что дано на входе (если это строка, то предпочтительнее использовать русские символы для более универсального примера) и что ожидается на выходе (конкретный результат, а не просто словесное описание), а то непонятно ничего

Comment: @D-side, по-моему проблема возникает при вызове `hashlib.md5(string_object)` - `hashlib.md5()` требует `"Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing"`

Comment: @MaxU не буду притворяться, что знаю Python; давайте подождём реакции от автора.

Comment: Спасибо, ссылка, приведенная выше, решила мою проблему. Мне нужно было что-то вроде str_to_byte(str) или str.tobyte(), т.к. функция hashlib.md5() принимает байтовую строку, в то время как в родительскую функцию (md5()) поступает строка utf-8.